# how to move site from a corrupted xampp to another xampp?

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, localhost, joomla3.0

i had a Joomla site on **Xampp** but for some reason i had to remove it but i copied all database files(OPT, MYI, MYD, FRM) and my folders in **htdocs** from previous **Xampp**
now i know the right way of backing up a site but now all i have from previous Xampp(recovery didn't work) is these two folders
now when i installed it once more and the "Quick start" of that first site and replaced htdocs and database folder with the previous site it's not like the original site

Comment: What is different?

Comment: @LordWilmore 
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table 'MYTABLE.#__session' doesn't exist SQL=DELETE FROM `#__session` WHERE `time` < '1470145791'

Comment: @LordWilmore it shows this error
i think the problem is with database connection
how can i export those db files?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your XAMPP installation folder, you will be having a Mysql folder and inside that folder you will have a data folder. You will find your Joomla database folder inside data folder. Copy the Joomla database folder to your new xampp installation. Paste it inside xampp->Mysql->data folder. Change the configuration.php databse connection details. Copy Joomla site folder to your new htdocs folder.